# Migrating to maven with multi modules

Tags: java, maven

I am currently migrating a project from Ant to Maven 3 along with a JBoss AS7 / Wildfly migration.

I am now having trouble over some client specific configuration.

I created a mutli-module project with a parent pom much like so:

```
Parent
  |___ Business
  |___ Ear
  |___ Ejb
  |___ Sar
  |___ War
  |___ GUI
  |...
```

This project is supposed to be configured, tweeked and delivered to different clients (at this moment, i am doing this only for one client)

Therefore, there is client specific code (EJBs, domain classes, specific GUIs) and client specific configuration present at all the different project levels (EJB, GUI, Core, ...).

In the previous configuration there was a single project for the client with an Ant build that took care of packaging, resource replacement in all the different modules.

I am taking a different approach where i created now client modules for the modules that are specific for client which amount to nearly all of them.

```
Parent
  |___ ... previous modules...
  |___ ...
  |___ Business-Client1
  |___ Ear-Client1
  |___ Ejb-Client1
  |___ Sar-Client1
  |___ War-Client1
  |___ GUI-Client1
  |...
```

All the *Client modules have an explicit dependency to their 'normal' couterpart.

Once theses modules are packaged, they are deployed on the JBoss instance.

Now for my questions :

- Am i taking the right approach, is there a simpler / 'mavenlier' way to do this (profiles, assembly ???) ?
- I have to override / change some configuration present in the 'normal' modules with the configuration of the client. How can i do that considering that the Client modules have a dependency to their counterpart and therefore maven packages them in that order ?

**EDIT :**

Renamed 'Core' project to Business so that i can talk about the core project and the client modules.

So far, i got a working core project that is deployed correctly to JBoss with the jboss-as-maven-plugin.

I have an EAR that contains a SAR, a WAR and a EJB modules.

Each module has a client counterpart. I think this is a bit heavy but its more 'modular'...

Here are some explanation of the project architecture :

The gui detects if a certain class implementing a `CustomInitialization` `interface` is present in the classpath.

This is the centerpoint where here, we can get client specific GUI or EJBs. For instance, the menu is overriden :

```
IMenu
  ^
  |
StdMenu
  ^
  |
ClientMenu
```

Therefore we can have a custom GUI for the menus, thus having new screens and so on.

For the EJB part, this is similar. In a ClientAction, we could have a call to a ClientEjb that can be entirely new or simply extending a core EJB.

This is the same for the model (database), configuration and resources . Most of the time, configuration files are simply duplicated in Client code and extended with client specific configuration, therefore there is no need to really merge them but simply to overwrite them.

Here are the modules as described by the parent pom for now :

```
<modules>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>ear</module>
    <module>util</module>
    <!-- Core contains the business model -->
    <module>core</module>
    <!-- Forget those two now -->
    <module>agentManager</module>
    <module>agent</module>
    <!-- service is SAR, maybe i won't need to overwrite that one -->
    <module>service</module>
    <module>gui</module>
    <!-- I am using a client.module variable... -->
    <module>gui-${client.module}</module>
    <module>ejb-${client.module}</module>
</modules>
```

**EDIT 2:**

In response to Engineer Dollery: its true that i don't need to merge everything and in fact i'm not really sure i need to, i have thought about it and i think the only real thing i have to do is to **overwrite the configuration and resources**.

- I am not entirely sure how to do that properly as client modules are packaged **after** core modules.

Notes:
The only downside of this approach for me is that it requires a lot of modules for the client code specificities.

By the way, the GUI module, a heavy client, will not need to be merged as it is deployed on the server as a jnlp file (overriden by client configuration and delivered by the WAR module).

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information to really help. I'd need to know what sort of client specific changes are in the client modules -- is it just property files and datasources, or is it code? As explained, your approach seems simple and effective, if a little long winded. If you don't have too many clients, then it is also simple and easy to reason about, which is a big benefit. If you can provide more info, we'll be glad to help more.

Comment: As stated, the client specific changes are property files / resources but also code changes via inheritance or simply new features. I will try to detail a bit more my approach.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage and disadvantage of using Maven is they tend to have a very restricted way of doing things based on what a group of people has deemed proper.  Personally I do prefer the Maven way, but if I have to deal with migrations of an existing app which wasn't mavenized in thinking to begin with, I would start with the ant run plugin to just import stuff to ant and use the maven assembly plugin to set up which parts to release.

Another approach would be to start with Gradle if you prefer the programming approach. I personally would avoid it because it makes things harder to ramp up for others in the future as it becomes very project specific even though it is easier for the first person to do it.

Client JARs would generally be in its own project separate from the EJB and WAR modules.

Though if this was a Java EE 6 and above project, I would eliminate the EJB modules and merge them into the WAR when applicable.   However, that would require a more detailed analysis on what your project is like.

If the client code is "generated" from the server code, the project should be simpler, in my case I had used [a separate project that just uses the plugin and no versioned source aside from tests](https://github.com/trajano/app/tree/master/app-ws).

Comment: Well i have an EAR module, it's just not shown (JEE6 used). The project is quite large and the client specific code overrides most of the modules (Client EJB inheritance with core project, GUI plugins/adaptations). The project has been going for almost 10 years so this is quite a difficult task. I have chose to migrate completely to maven because i needed to migrate to JBoss 7 as well. Ant scripts were simply too immutable to be rewritten for that task.

Comment: Agreed, but you need to do things in stages.  That's why I suggested use the ant run plugin first, then move things out.  The EAR file is the easiest to build out first, but you have to get it to emit the right JAR files that reside in the EAR, that's where maven assembly plugin comes in.  Then start breaking the components down based on your needs.  Personal plug: you may want to hire a short term contractor who has experience in these things to do it for you as it is a one time chore.  I suggest looking for people in Careers@stackoverflow.com to do it.

Comment: The EAR is done and working. The only real problem now is packaging the client specific modules with the core modules. I need a way to figure out how i can merge them. I thought also that i had to look into the assembly plugin, but i stopped as i read that it was designed for delivery only. Was i wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure that you should 'merge' anything. The client modules should depend on the core modules and override/extend anything they need to. War files can be 'overlayed'

Comment: Assembly can be used to extract other JARs and merge them to form another jar.  Maven Shade Plugin can also be used for that but I found that assembly was easier to deal with and Shade was useful for some specific things like creating an uberjar (which based on your last comment sounds like would fit in better).